# How to integrate Batch with Firebase in my ios App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, firebase

I'm using Firebase as a backend for my ios app and i want to use push notifications, so i did a little research and i found out that Batch can be integrated with firebase to resolve the issu of push notifications, can anybody help me to integrate Batch to Firebase or advise me to a better alternatives to use for my App ? 
Thanks

Comment: You need this link : https://batch.com/parse-replacement-with-firebase

Comment: thanks for your answer but the problem is that the transactional api provided by batch is not included in the free membership plan

Comment: It says the basic free batch membership does include the transactional api.  Maybe this was recently added?